# Cannot import dependency from GitLab Package Registry

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

I've got Java Application which I want to use remotely as dependency. I have uploaded it into GitLab Package Registry. I can add dependency to my target projects and InteliJIdea sees it, but I cannot import and use it in target project's classes.

***this is pom.xml in target project***

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.elmojke</groupId>
        <artifactId>issue-tracker</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

***this is settings.xml in source project***

```
<settings>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <configuration>
            <httpHeaders>
                <property>
                    <name>Private-Token</name>
                    <value>My-Token-Value-Is-Here</value>
                </property>
            </httpHeaders>
        </configuration>
    </server>
</servers>
```

***this is pom.xml in source project***

```
<groupId>com.elmojke</groupId>
<artifactId>issue-tracker</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>issue-tracker</name>
<description>issue-tracker</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/37087069/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/37087069/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/37087069/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[this is the error I get in target project's class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EZMa.png)

What it could be? I've tried adding settings.xml and repository section into target pom.xml, but it did not help me at all. I get the same error with GitHub Package Registry. Also, I used maven command to get the dependency
`mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.elmojke:issue-tracker:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` but still no result.

Comment: Try look inside the jar to see if it looks right

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen what do you mean by that? Maybe I am doing something weird during the process because it just ignores any kind of imports but I tried to call for a static method and it worked without any import.